# Selecting from a table with two separate indexes is not using a key depending on value in where clause

Tags: mysql, explain

I am tuning our database indices and discovered some strange behavior in Mysql 5.7.32. Here is a script to replicate the issue.

I have a table `employees` with three columns `id`, `firstname` and `lastname`. There are two indexes on the table for each of the varchar columns. For one of the SELECT statements below, the output is unexpectedly not using the key.

Why is one of those queries not using the index? Is it because `Miller` is the first value in the table? Or is this an inaccuracy of EXPLAIN?

```
DROP TABLE if EXISTS `employee`;
CREATE TABLE `employee` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    `firstname` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `lastname` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`), 
    INDEX `index_firstname` (`firstname`),
    INDEX `index_lastname` (`lastname`)
);

INSERT INTO `employee` (firstname,lastname) VALUES('alice','Miller');
INSERT INTO `employee` (firstname,lastname) VALUES('bob','Miller');
INSERT INTO `employee` (firstname,lastname) VALUES('charlie','Miller');
INSERT INTO `employee` (firstname,lastname) VALUES('doyle','Miller');
INSERT INTO `employee` (firstname,lastname) VALUES('evan','Smith');
INSERT INTO `employee` (firstname,lastname) VALUES('franz','Smith');
INSERT INTO `employee` (firstname,lastname) VALUES('gloria','Smith');
INSERT INTO `employee` (firstname,lastname) VALUES('helga','Unique');

EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM employee WHERE firstname='alice';   # uses the key 'index_firstname'
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM employee WHERE lastname='Smith';    # uses the key 'index_lastname'
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM employee WHERE lastname='Unique';   # uses the key 'index_lastname'

EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM employee WHERE lastname='Miller';   # does not use the key 'index_lastname'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where a sampling of index values has over a ~25% ratio (not exact, see below) of sampling of the given value, the index isn't used.

There is a cost calculation that works out that scanning the full table is faster than using the secondary index (which needs to fetch from the primary table to retrieve `*`).

Comment: Aha, that explains it. I could verify that the query will start using the index by adding a few more rows with a different `lastname`. Also: when selecting only the `lastname` column instead of `*`, it will use the index even if the ratio is higher. thanks!